# How to retrieve all managed properties using csom or powershell in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, managed-property

I want get a list of all custom managed properties from the SharePoint online site. Is there any way to get it using managed csom(c#) or powershell?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing and research, there is no way to get all managed properties using CSOM or PowerShell in SharePoint online. On SharePoint Server, you can get the managed properties via 'Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty'.

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved. If there's anything you'd like to know, don't hesitate to ask.